# eclipse don't recognize my sony xperia mini pro for debuging program directly

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-xml

i have installed:
 1:sony ericsson pc companion
 2:SEMC_Signed usb Driver
 3.updated my eclipse->available packages..

[image]

but while running program it will not detect the phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to try:

1. Make sure you don't have one of those cheap $2 knockoff USB interface cables. I banged my head for an hour or two before I realized the reason my PC wouldn't see my phone is because of my cable.
2. Drop to command prompt, type adb kill-server and then adb devices to restart the adb server.
3. Make sure your phone is in debug mode (settings > applications > development > enable USB debugging)