# Tablet not appearing in ADB

Tags: android, adb

I've just got a Lenovo Thinkpad Slate Tablet running Android and can't for the life of me get ADB to recognise it in either Win7 or Kubuntu.

USB debugging is on in the tablet settings and when I connect the tablet to the computer the "USB Debugging Connected" message appears - so all good from the tablet side of things.  The computer side of things isn't so great.

**Kubuntu** (my main dev machine)

I've added the vendor id to the /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file (as directed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)) - have tried each of the below, one at a time, with no success.

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666"`

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="17EF", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="17EF", MODE="0666"`

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666"`

For reference I have 
`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`
for my Nexus S and it works fine.

`lsusb` prints out:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/udev/rules.d# lsusb
...
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 17ef:741b Lenovo 
...
```

**Windows**

Have followed [these instructions](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/enable-adb-usb-drivers-for-nvidia-tegra-based-android-tablets/) and still not getting any response from adb devices.

I've restarted both machines and the tablet several times to no avail. Can anyone help?

Comment: No need for "*fixed*" tag in question. PLease accept the correct answer, or add your own.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Creating the file ~/.android/adb_usb.ini and adding the vendor id (0x17ef) and restarting adb seems to have fixed the issue in both Windows and Kubuntu.

Comment: Do you literally just add `0x17ef` on a line in this file?

Comment: I believe so - this was a while ago and I can't quite remember, but you should have a look at https://apkudo.com/?p=676 (One true adb_usb.ini to rule them all)

Comment: it seems to work for most devices, except my Itel it702.. Any help with this?

Comment: As a reference, here is a list of vendors' IDs: https://gist.github.com/jdamcd/6054951

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with the Lenovo's page. My thinkpad was listed under portable devices and following the directions got me "Unable to find drive for your device". I was able to remedy by search internet for updates (which updated to a USB driver and this moved my Thinkpad to the other device's category in the Device Manager). I then was able to use the instructions as listed on the web page.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried several ways, especially posts from Lenovo forum but no luck. Finally, I have found my way.

1. Enabling USB debugging
2. Download the driver from [Lenovo](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/adb_driver_20110720.zip), unzip and update your device driver. I think some people would be success as @Pooks answer then you can stop. Otherwise, continue as below.
3. If latest driver does not help or Windows could not install driver for your device, let check its Hardware Ids. Mine is USB\VID_17EF&PID_741B
4. Open the android_winusb.inf, find these settings

   [Google.NTamd64]
   ;Lenovo Think Tablet
   %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_17EF&PID_741B
   %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_17EF&PID_741B&MI_01
   %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_17EF&PID_741C&MI_01
   %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_17EF&PID_741D&MI_02
   %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_17EF&PID_741E&MI_02

Mine is USB\VID_17EF&PID_741B, so I just remove the rest. Now it looks like

```
[Google.NTamd64]
;Lenovo Think Tablet
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_17EF&PID_741B
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_17EF&PID_741B&MI_01
```

For now, just update your driver again. Windows should install your device properly. You can check the device connection by ADB devices, mine is

```
C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached 
MP0398W device
```

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the drivers using the Lenovo Smart Assistance program from Lenovo's page:

Just download, install and run the program.

http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/tablets/a-series/a10-70-tablet

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452898/eclipse-dont-recognize-my-sony-xperia-mini-pro-for-debuging-program-directly/7452950#7452950) question. One of the things to make sure of is that you are not using a cheap $2 knock-off USB cable. I did this once and couldn't figure out WHY my computer would not recognize my phone. Replacing the cable fixed everything.

Comment: This has happened to me so many times!  I've spent hours pulling my hair out because of cruddy cables.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work by going to Lenovo's [ADB Interface Driver - ThinkPad Tablet](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS022366) download page and following the installation instructions there. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

There might be a lot of issue, but after you do the basic steps like enabling USB debugging and all, if still it does not work follow below steps which helped me for ubuntu (all tablets):

1. open terminal, type lsusb, it will show all the devices connected. Find out the vendor id of your device.(Try disconnecting and run command lsusb and the reconnect and try lsusb command, you will find out which is your device. so against your device you will find something like 0574:4798 XYZ COrp.). So 574 is your vendor id.

eg:
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:e784 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b249 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

a5c is my vendor id

1. type cd .android in terminal
2. open adb_usb.ini
3. add 0xa5c in new line.
4. save and close.
5. kill adb-server or sudo kill adb-server
6. start adb-server or start adb-server
7. sudo killall adb
8. connect your device in debug mode.
9. Voila you are good to go my friend.

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu, I just added `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"` to my `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file. Restarted adb, and then it worked!